# SSL handshake error on sauce labs with internet explorer

Tags: ssl, protractor, saucelabs

Protractor tests in other browsers work ok but with IE (all versions) we get the following error when we look at screenshots of each test

[image: screenshot from sauce]:

'Could not proxy https://somewebsite-that-isn't-behind-firewall.com
java.langRuntimeException: Couldn't establish SSL handshake.  Try using trustAllSSLCerficates.
Received fatal alert: handshake_failure'

Tried adding the following flags to the `conf.js` file:

`'acceptSSLCerts': true`

`'trustAllSSLCerficates': true`

...but neither makes any difference.

Comment: That screenshot looks awfully "XP"ey to me.  Could it be that the server doesn't support the old, broken cipher suites that IE on XP needs to use?

Comment: It does look that way but the config file calls out lists operating system and browser version which are Windows 10 and IE 11 for this test, unless sauce labs is just ignoring that.

Comment: at least for IE11 on Browserstack the answer was:

`'trustAllSslCertificates': 'true'`

Unfortunately this isn't a complete answer and doesn't work for all versions of IE in Browserstack and doesn't seem to fix anything in Saucelabs.

Answer (score 0):

Docs: https://wiki.saucelabs.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=48365781

Should resolve the issue by using the `-B` command